# C array of pointers on top level without size declaration

Tags: c, pointers

This code compiles and produce output like I would expect.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* ar[];

int main(void) {    
    ar[0] = 97;
    ar[1] = 98;
    ar[2] = 99;

    printf("%i\n", ar[0]);
    printf("%i\n", ar[1]);
    printf("%i\n", ar[2]);
    printf("%i\n", ar[3]);

    return 0;
}

/* output
97
98
99
0
*/
```

I have a feeling that I'm doing this wrong on so many levels. Are there any ill effects here, what are they?

Moreover, why does the array of pointers work as global variable, while if I declare it in `main`, gcc raises an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least couple problems:

1) `ar` is an array of pointers - you're assigning ints to it (and printing the elements as ints). I get warnings about this from both GCC and MSVC.

2) the declaration of `ar` is an 'incomplete type' since it doesn't have the size specified.  MSVC refuses to link saying that it can't resolve the `ar` symbol, which is what I'd expect.  GCC does link, providing a warning:

```
warning: array 'ar' assumed to have one element
```

I prefer the MSVC behavior in this case.

In GCC's case, you're accessing data for 3 or 4 array elements with only 1 element actually existing, so you're accessing memory that doesn't properly belong to an object, which is undefined behavior.  It'll result in memory corruption, a crash, or apparently working - even though the program isn't correct (as in your test).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out 1. I feel rather silly right about now :P  I guess I was mainly confused by it actually working. I agree that gcc shouldn't link it.

Comment: I couldn't find a normative reference, but C11 (n1570) 6.9.2 p5 (an example) indicates, that the behaviour of `gcc` is the required behaviour. Though I agree that this isn't a useful feature.

Answer (score 2):

Two words: undefined behavior. If it's in main, gcc can tell `ar` hasn't been given any space because its scope is limited to the stack. When `ar` is global, the compiler can't ensure that nobody's allocated space for it. There may be ill effects on some systems and on others it may run fine. The point is that it won't always do what you expect because what it does is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

int *a[] is an array of pointers. And it is an empty array to which you haven't allocated any space. The behavior of the code is undefined.. gcc raising/not raising an error is the least of your worries.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare

```
int ar[4]
```

you would have been alright. In that case ar is global and initialized to 
4 zeroes. You setting values in main then overrides the 0's.

But without dimension, no go.

Comment: Not to mention, it's an array of int*, not int.

Comment: yes, mine is a double correction: type of array determined, and of type int.