# compiling outdated c++ package: undefined reference errors

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile a system called [SNoW](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/1) in Ubuntu using g++ 4.4.5. The software seems to have been last updated for g++ 3.1.4, as I found a switch inside one of the files that checked for it and the highest case was 3.1.4 +.

I had to update a few of the headers to get past compiler errors ... cstring instead of string and things like that. Now I'm stuck on undefined reference errors, where the the undefined reference is to a function in a header which is provided.

The error is this:

```
Main.o: In function `ShowUsage(char const*)':
Main.cpp:(.text+0x140e): undefined reference to `Fex::logo'
```

... which comes from this in Main.cpp:

```
cerr << Fex::logo[0] << endl;
```

Where Fex.h is included at the top of Main.cpp, and one of the *public* members of the class Fex in Fex.h is this:

```
static const char * logo[];
```

The Makefile for Main.o is thus:

```
fex : Main.o 
    $(CC) -O2 -o fex Main.o $(LINKFLAGS)

Main.o : Main.cpp FexGlobalParams.h Fex.h libfex.a
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o Main.o Main.cpp
```

I've tried setting CC to the earliest version of g++ in the repos (4.3) and re-ordering the headers in the Makefile to no success, and am not sure what to do at this point. I can't find an extant copy of g++ 3.1, and the software creators are quite convinced it compiled under Linux the last time they worked on it.

Does anyone spot what may be wrong, or have any suggestions for things to try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the declaration of the static member might be in the `Fex.h` header, there needs to be a single *definition* of the member somewhere (generally it would be in a `Fex.cpp` file):

```
const char * Fex::logo[ /* you'll need some size here, too */ ];
```

<strike>I seem to recall that GCC would automatically gen up a definition for these 'phantom' static members - maybe they've changed that (or added a compiler option)?</strike> - I was thinking of GCC [assuming that statically allocated arrays without a specified size would default to one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207991/c-array-of-pointers-on-top-level-without-size-declaration/4208066#4208066), but that's C only.

Comment: Aha! Fex::logo is defined in Fex.cpp, but Fex.cpp was compiled after Main.cpp in the Makefile. 

I changed the order and now it compiles. :D 

Thanks!

Comment: @Hydrangea: that's weird.  It shouldn't matter about the compilation order as long as `Fex.cpp` is compiled at some point and `Fex.o` is linked in ("undefined reference" is a linker error).

Comment: Yeah... that doesn't make any sense. I tried to replicate it by putting things back in the original order and then repeating the process, and it compiled in the original order again.

Comment: It looks like you might be packaging `Fex.o` into `libfex.a` - I wonder if the makefile isn't properly handling `libfex.a` and its dependencies correctly?